# Finding the image of $f$ given by $f(x)=\frac {2x^2-x}{3x^2+x+1}$ for $\forall x\in [0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I found the image of $$f(x)=\dfrac {2x^2-x}{3x^2+x+1}$$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ using the method of $f(x)=b$ then checking when the discriminant is positive I got that it's positive between $-1/11\le b\le 1$ but now I need to find the image just for positive reals and I know that it becomes smaller from the graph.

What is the method to find the image for just positive (or negative) reals?

Note: I can't use limits or derivatives/integrals, nor $\epsilon, \delta$.